# Sharing folders (read only folder inside write folder)

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I have several Windows 7 computers. I have one shared folder on one PC (permission full control). Inside this folder I want to have one folder that has read only share permission. I want only one Network location for other computers. It's easy to setup with two Network locations. Is it possible what I want? (using Security tab in Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible. You would need to ensure that the inner folder is not inheriting security rights from its parent.